# multiplying 2 matrices to get the 0 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

if I have a $m \times n$ matrix $A$, and a $n \times m$ matrix $B$, such as $AB = 0$. Also, $A$ and $B$ are not $0$.
Does it mean that the homogeneous matrix equation $Ax=0$ have non-trivial solution?

Is it true also about $B$ ?

I am pretty sure it is true for $A$ and not true for $B$.
but i couldn't figure out how to prove it.

Edit:
I think I figured it out. 
If $M \lt N$ then there are more variables then equations and hence $Ax=0$ have non-trivial solution.
if $M \geq N$ that means that if $A$ has only a trivial solution then $A$ has a left inverse. and then by multiplying it with $A^{-1}$ we would get $I$, and them $B$ must be $0$.
 $$
AB = 0\quad  =>\quad A^{-1}AB=0\quad =>\quad IB=0\quad =>\quad B=0
$$

For B on the other hand it is not true. because if $N<M $ then it has a right inverse. but if $N>M$ then it is not have a right inverse.

Comment: only square matrices have determinants.  You should edit your question to reflect this fact.

Comment: With respect to the edit: only square matrices have inverses.

Comment: @user84451 : of course, only square matrices can be "invertible" as well.  Please fix your question for future users' sake even if someone manages to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the non-square case, a simple example for $n < m$ is to chose $2n$ vectors $u_i \in \mathbb R^m$ with $u_i^T u_j = 0$ if $i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ and $j\in\{n+1, \ldots, 2n\}$ and set
$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}u_1^T\\\vdots\\u_n^T\end{matrix}\right)$$
and
$$B = \left(\begin{matrix}.\\u_{n+1} \cdots u_{2n}\\.\end{matrix}\right)$$

---

A simple example would be
$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}1&0&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1&0&\ldots&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
and
$$B = \left(\begin{matrix}0&\ldots&0\\1&\ldots&1\\0&\ldots&0\\\vdots&&\vdots\\0&\ldots&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Can you give a numeric example?

Comment: @user844541 Added $u_i = e_1$ for $i \leq n$ and $u_i = e_2$ for $i > n$ where $e_i \in \mathbb R^m$

Comment: @user844541 If this solved the question for you, please mark it as solved. If not, feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the question. At the end I chose for a numeric example  B as 1XN vector - it is much easier.